# How to resolve a Flow(InferError) getting for FocusOptions?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, typechecking

I am getting a **Flow Error** for following line

`element.focus({ preventScroll: true });`

[image]

But it should support ***preventScroll*** property for **FocusOptions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have to upgrade **flow**

This issue is related to https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7651